# jquery variables in functions, how to handle globals?

Tags: jquery, global-variables

I have an ajax call in jquery which returns 4 different arrays.
3 of these arrays i want to use outside of the ajax success function and the data in the arrays should be accessible for certain click events.

I just don't know the best way to handle the array variables. 
some people say going global is a bad idea and other say its ok.. so

ajax success function:
does stuff with one of the arrays

array1, array2 needs to be used by other functions and click events

```
function display_results_1(){
$('#myDiv').html(array1.id);
}


$('#binfo').click(function(){
    $('#client_info_div').dialog({

    $('#myDiv').html(array2.id);

    });
})
```

This is my ajax call:

```
  $('#c_search').submit(function(){
           data = ($(this).serialize());

          $.ajax({
              url: 'actions/get_company.php',
              type: 'POST',
              data: data,
              cache: false,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(selected){
`doing stuff here`
    })
    })
```

Should I use separate Ajax calls to get the data when needed for each different function?

Comment: Going global is not a good idea for your javascript.  Avoid polluting the global namespace where possible.

Comment: That is the consensuses, so how do I place these variables in the right place so that jquery can use them, do i pass them to the function that will use them after they are retrieved(without calling the function)? will they 'sit' their until that function is actually called?

Comment: The consensus is that you should use anonymous functions as a "namespace" to keep everything clean, compartmentalized, and easy on memory management. What people often fail to mention, though, is that it takes an advanced level of javascript knowledge to pull it off (you will run into scope and closure issues that will have you dropkicking your monitor at some point). If you are not ready for that then go ahead and use global variables.

Comment: @Adam, Would you rather query the database with Ajax calls as needed to produce each array individually and on demand or load all items from one query like above and use Globals/namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely don't want your variables in the global scope, but you could wrap everything in a function to prevent them from being in the global scope:

```
$(function() {
    var array1 = [];
    var array2 = [];

    function display_results_1(){
$('#myDiv').html(array1.id);
}


$('#binfo').click(function(){
    $('#client_info_div').dialog({

    $('#myDiv').html(array2.id);

    });
})

$('#c_search').submit(function(){
           data = ($(this).serialize());

          $.ajax({
              url: 'actions/get_company.php',
              type: 'POST',
              data: data,
              cache: false,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(selected){
`doing stuff here`
    })
    })

});
```

By doing this you'll ensure that the code is also running on page load, notice the $() wrapping the function.

See http://api.jquery.com/ready/ for more info.

Contrary to the previous answers, going global is NOT a good idea.  You may end up having multiple pieces of JavaScript using the same variables.

Comment: Thank you SoWeLie.. Seems concise and I think will get me going in the right direction...

Comment: You're welcome, you may also want to read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript.  As you add more and more JavaScript it can become pretty cumbersome.  If you organize your JavaScript into objects, it can help to keep things cleaner.

Comment: Just one question... the json array is selected.array1 and selected.array2. So inside the success function do i assign these to the already declared array1 and array2 variables?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the arrays to the window object inside the ajax success function:

```
function ajaxSuccess(response){
    window.array1 = response.array1;
    window.array2 = response.array2;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to be used outside the success function then set a variable outside the function.

```
var myarray1= new Array();

$.ajax(function() {....
    success(function(data) {
       myarray1 = data.array
```

Don't worry about "going global", if you need a variable outside the scope of a function, then set it where you need it. A good place may be at the beginning of `$(document).ready()`